# Comparing fuel efficiency using R

Tags: statistics, math-software, means

I am given two data sets.

Small Cars

```
3 | 3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,6,7,7,7 
4 | 5
5 | 0
```

Sporty Cars

```
2 | 9,9,9,9,9,9,9
3 | 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3
```

I am then asked to find the mean but I am not sure how to do that in R. I get to the point where I get the values on a table where the columns are MPG, Small, Sporty. But not sure what to do afterwards. And I am new to R so it is a bit harder.

Comment: I've rolled back the edit because it substantially changed the data in question.

Comment: @T.Bongers Really? I would like to know how it does

Comment: @Anonymous Sporty cars went from having 32 show up four times to zero. It had 31 show up once instead of six times. There's already an answer that used this particular data.

Comment: @T.Bongers I see. I'll fix that. EDIT: FIXED

Answer (score 2):

Very elementary, very short lesson in R:

After the prompts `<`in the R session window, type what I have below.
Do the same for 'Sporty' cars. Note the `c` at the beginning of the data,
the commas after each observation and the parentheses. You could make
a data frame as shown in another answer. That is a good thing to learn,
especially if you are given a data file with the observations. But for
printed (rather than digital) data, you have to type the observations
anyway, so what I'm showing you is easier.

```
> Small = c(50, 45, 37, 37, 37, 36, 35, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 33, 33, 33, 33)
> mean(Small)
[1] 35.94444
> summary(Small)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  33.00   34.00   34.00   35.94   36.75   50.00 
> sd(Small)
[1] 4.504537
> boxplot(Small, col="skyblue", pch=19)
```

Notice that the median and the lower quartile are the same, so the
median 'cross bar'; coincides with the lower end of the 'box' in the
boxplot. (Try `boxplot(Small)`, leaving out parameters 'col' and 'pch'; you'll
get a slightly less fancy boxplot.)

[image]

You could make
a data frame as shown in the answer of @SiongthyGoth. That is a good thing to learn,
especially if you are given a data file with the observations. But for
printed (rather than digital) data, you have to type the observations
anyway, so what I'm showing you is easier.

R is a very useful (and free!) statistical software package. You will go crazy
if you try to learn it all at once. Take one small step, like this one, at a
time and you will be happy using R.

---

More (when ready):

```
> Sporty = c(33,32,32,32,32,31,31,31,31,31,31,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,29,29,29,29,29,29,29)
> mean(Sporty)
[1] 30.4
> All = c(Small, Sporty)
> mean(All)
[1] 32.72093
> length(Small)
[1] 18
> length(Sporty)
[1] 25
> Type = c(rep(1, 18), rep(2,25))
> boxplot(All ~ Type, col="wheat", pch=19)
```

[image]

```
> t.test(Small, Sporty)

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  Small and Sporty 
t = 5.0956, df = 18.719, p-value = 6.717e-05
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0 
95 percent confidence interval:
 3.264730 7.824159 
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 35.94444  30.40000
```

Because of the very small P-value, we conclude that MPGs are significantly
different for the two types of cars.

```
> stripchart(All ~ Type, meth="stack", pch=20)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the mean() function on a numeric vector to return the mean. If your data table is called "df", and the column you want to find the mean for is called "MPG", then you can use mean(df[["MPG"]]) to get the mean for the column MPG.

Comment: but what if i want the mean of MPG for Small cars? and then the mean of MPG for Sporty cars?

Comment: You can do the same thing - use mean(df[["small"]]) and mean(df[["sporty"]]). The thing inside the quotations should be the name of your column. The "df" should be replaced by the name of your table.

Comment: But that would take the mean of the "small" column right? I am looking to find the mean using the MPG and the amount of small cars. But how is that done?

Comment: Can you edit your post and include an example of how your data looks? Try using head() on your table to get the first few rows of the table (e.g. with "head(df)").

Answer (score 1):

Some examples to help you to start.

data(mtcars) #load a data set, mtcars is the name of the dataframe.

mean(mtcars$mpg) #compute the mean for mpg features for the dataframe mtcars